# Hibernate doesn't see JDBC driver in Tomcat/lib but only in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, jdbc

I am start using Hibernate with JSF web applications (without Spring) and I have folowing questions:

1. I have installed Tomcat with PostgreSQL JDBC driver in tomcat's lib
   folder, but seems like Hibernate don't see is and I need to copy
   `postgresql-jdbc.jar` file in `WEB-INF/lib`. Is it normal behavior?
2. Say, I have several JSF projects deployed in one Tomcat server. I need to have hibernate jars, JSF libraries and other jars in
   `WEB-INF/lib` each application, or there are some way to install
   Hibernate, JSF and other commonly used libraries on Tomcat to
   minimize project `war` size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can put our all jars into tomcat lib folder no need to add for all projects. But if you are running from eclipse then add these to your build path else it won't run.

In our environment we have configured tomcat in server and will put all jars in lob folder. Then we will deploy war without jar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use maven for building projects and all the dependencies can be configured by maven.